# jQuery: AddClass

Tags: jquery, css

I have a list, where SPANs contains a number. I want to "copy" this number to a STYLE (setting width to the number as percentage) on a SPAN next to it.

**HTML**

```
<span class="celebName">Per</span>
<span class="celebPct">32</span>
<span class="celebBar"></span>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('.celebPct').each(function(index) {
    var celebPct = $(this).val();
    $(this).next(".celebBar").css({"width": + $(celebPct)+"%";});
});
```

**I want outcome to be like this:**

```
<span class="celebName">Per</span>
<span class="celebPct">32</span>
<span class="celebBar" style="width:32%;"></span>
```

Why doesn't this work??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('.celebPct').each(function(index) {
    var celebPct = $(this).text();
    $(this).next(".celebBar").css({"width":  celebPct+"%"});
});
```

Here is a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/beK89/

Also if you only have one css change you don't need an object in the `.css` call, you can just do: `.css("width",  celebPct+"%");`

Answer (score 1):

Spans don't have values so try text instead:

```
var celebPct = $(this).text();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `val()` on a span, you'll want to use `text()`.  Also the syntax for your css options is wrong.  You can set one option without using an object. Plus the return value from `text()` is a string value, not jQuery so you needn't wrap it with jQuery when concatenating.

```
$('.celebPct').each(function(index) {
    var celebPct = $(this).text();
    $(this).next(".celebBar").css( "width", celebPct+"%" );
});
```

Answer (score 1):

- use `text()` not `val()` to get inner text of a div. val is for inputs
- no need to wrap the resulting `celebPct` into a jquery
- you had a few **syntax errors** in the hash you passed into css

cleaned up:

```
$('.celebPct').each(function(index) {
   var celebPct = $(this).text();
   $(this).next(".celebBar").css({"width": celebPct+"%"});
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be wrong:

```
var celebPct = $(this).val();
```

use

```
$(this).html()
```

instead, because span dont have .val only inputs/selects have it.

so this should be the code:

```
$('.celebPct').each(function(index) {
    var celebPct = $(this).html();
    $(this).next(".celebBar").css({"width": celebPct + "%";});
});
```

no need to use $(celebPct) as celebPct is not a jquery element